# Workers not starting in Storm (backtype.storm.daemon.worker class not found)

Tags: bigdata, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-storm

I’m a newbie with Storm and I have setup a Storm-on-Yarn on an HDP cluster using the instructions at the HDP Storm-on-Yarn page and the storm-yarn-master from anfeng's storm-yarn git project.

I’m able to get Nimbus running and even submit topologies and see them on Storm UI. However, the spouts and the bolts don’t seem to be “working” (0 counts of tuples emitted).

I did some digging around and realized that my worker daemons are not starting. The supervisor log spits out these:

```
2014-03-13 11:22:03 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 18bf93a1-1cea-4e99-93da-8f36a4e9c056 still hasn't started
```

I tried launching the worker command from the “Launching worker with command” line in the supverviser log and I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: backtype/storm/daemon/worker
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: backtype.storm.daemon.worker
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Could not find the main class: backtype.storm.daemon.worker.  Program will exit.
```

It looks like it can’t find the worker class although it’s present in the storm-core jar.

Any ideas on how I can proceed with troubleshooting this? I’ve attached the nimbus and the supervisor logs. The worker logs don't seem to have been created.

Nimbus Log - http://paste.ubuntu.com/7089418/
Supervisor Log - http://paste.ubuntu.com/7089422/

Hadoop Version - 2.2
Storm Version - 0.9.0-wip21

Answer (score 0):

I've had an issue like this when the JAR file I was creating did not exclude the storm binaries. i.e. in the pom.xml file, make sure that you have the storm-core dependency set with:

```html
<scope>provided</scope>
```

As well, I had issues where multiple versions of netty were installed in the storm lib folder (had to delete the old version JAR). This was also causing NoClassDefFoundErrors to be thrown (albeit, different than the one you are experiencing).

I would suggest looking at the classpath that shows up when you submit the topolgies (you can do that by doing **ps -Af | grep storm**)